# Duvidas de Alinhamento entre duas Tables

Tags: css3

Tenho uma pequena duvida sobre o alinhamento entre essas as duas table
   `<table id="tableCabecVendasML">`   e   `<table id="tableDadosVendasML">`

OBS: Fiz esta pagina dessa maneira porque quero usa-la em uma sistema da empresa, não quero rolagem de tela  e quero que tenha uma lista de dados sem paginação, por isso o "header" fixo

[veja exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/GuMaximus/4112jouh/)

**HTML e CSS**

```css
html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

#divAreaSite {
    background: #cad5c5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#divAreaConteudo {
    background: #abb4a6;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    height: 100%;
}


#LinhaCabec {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}


#tableEstrutura, td,tr {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#tableEstrutura {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#LinhaTitulo {
    background-color: #0fcc15;
    height: 20px;
}

#LinhaMenu {
    background-color: #cc71cc;
    height: 20px;
}

#LinhaRodape {
    background-color: #cc71cc;
    height: 20px;
}
#AreaDados {
    background-color: #cccc8e;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#tableCabecVendasML {
    width: 100%;
    //position: relative;
}

#tableDadosVendasML {
    width: 100%;
    //height: 100%;
}

.ColCodigo {
    width: 20%;
}
.ColNomeCliente {
    width: 20%;
}

.ColData {
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
   <header>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
      <title>Vendas Mercado Livre</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ver_vendas_mercadolivre.css">
   </header>
   <body>
      <div id="divAreaSite">
         <div id="divAreaConteudo">
            <table id="tableEstrutura">
               <tr>
                  <td id="LinhaTitulo" colspan="2">Titulo</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td id="LinhaMenu" colspan="2">Menu</td>
               </tr>
               <tr id="LinhaCabec">
                  <td rowspan="2">menu  <br> Lateral </td>
                  <td>
                     <table id="tableCabecVendasML">
                        <tr>
                           <td class="ColCodigo"> Código </td>
                           <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Nome do Clinte </td>
                           <td class="ColData"> Data</td>
                        </tr>
                     </table>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <div id="AreaDados">
                        <table id="tableDadosVendasML">
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> AAAAAAAAA</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> 12121212</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> sdasdsd</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> sdasdsd</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> 12121212</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> sdasdsd</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> sdasdsd</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> 12121212</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> sdasdsd</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> sdasdsd</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> 12121212</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> sdasdsd</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> 12121212</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> sdasdsd</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> sdasdsd</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> 12121212</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> sdasdsd</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> sdasdsd</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> 12121212</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> sdasdsd</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> sdasdsd</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> 12121212</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> sdasdsd</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> 12121212</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> sdasdsd</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> sdasdsd</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> 12121212</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> sdasdsd</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> sdasdsd</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> 12121212</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> sdasdsd</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> sdasdsd</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> 12121212</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> sdasdsd</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> Coluna 3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="ColCodigo"> sdasdsd</td>
                              <td class="ColNomeCliente"> Coluna 2</td>
                              <td class="ColData"> The END </td>
                           </tr>
                        </table>
                       </div>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td id="LinhaRodape" colspan="2">Rodape</td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gustavo, Acredito que a melhor maneira, seria criar uma tabela única e "fixar" o cabeçalho. Assim a barra de navegação não vai interferir no tamanho das colunas, porém, o trabalho de fixar o cabeçalho de uma tabela não é fácil. Eu achei 2 exemplos em puro css e html:
<ul>
<li> <a href="https://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu">https://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu</a> </li>
<li> <a href="https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/">https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/</a> </li>
</ul>